# Use specialization from base class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that inherits from a base class. The derived class has a template method. The base class has a specialized version of this method:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  public:
    static void print(int i) { std::cout << "Base::print\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    static void print(bool b) { std::cout << "Derived::bool_print\n"; }

    template <typename T>
    static void print(T t) { std::cout << "Derived::print\n"; }
    
    void Foo() {
        print(1);
        print(true);
        print("foo");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Derived::print
Derived::bool_print
Derived::print
```

The desired output is:

```
Base::print
Derived::bool_print
Derived::print
```

See code at https://onlinegdb.com/BY2znq8WV

Is there any way to tell `Derived::Foo` to use the specialization from `Base` instead of using the unspecialized version define in `Derived`?

**Edit**

The above example might be oversimplified as @Erdal Küçük showed. In actuality Derived subclasses from Base using CRTP, so it is not known if Base has a `print` method. A fuller example can be found at https://onlinegdb.com/N2IKgp0FY

Comment: Yes, `Base::print(1);`, although w.r.t C++ terminology there are no specializations in your code, just overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::print; //one of the many useful usages of the keyword 'using'
    //...
};
```

See: [Using-declaration in class definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition)

Comment: Oh, cool! So this doesn't quite work for my actual use case. I provided a simplified code in my example. But in reality, Derived, gets Base as a template arg (CRTP), I want, when Base has a print method to prefer it but otherwise use Derived's method. This code doesn't compile when Base doesn't have a print method.

Comment: I created a better example at https://onlinegdb.com/N2IKgp0FY

Comment: You've changed the rules in mid game. My example will of course not compile if `Base` has no such member. Which C++ standard are we talking about?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. C++ 17

Comment: If you want I can accept your answer and post this as a separate question.

Comment: @BenjyKessler That sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: Since @PaulSanders agrees too, do it.